BibLatex: Context-aware parentheses around citation year
I would like to achieve the following:

If a citation (\textcite{}) does not occur within parentheses, then the citation year (and page number, if any) should be parenthesized, like so: As Wright (1983) argues, ...
If a citation appears within parentheses, then the citation year should not be parenthesized, like so: (see Perry 1995 for details)

Here is a mwe:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sorting=nyt,
    doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\cite}{\textcite}


% The following changes the page citation style from 1997, p. 173 to 1997: 173
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  page             = {},
  pages            = {},
}

\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}

\addbibresource{sources.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

Citations such as this one show up how I want them to: \cite[10]{Walsh2015-WALRCA-5} show that Hume's Principle is internally
categorical.

However, citations in parentheses (such as this one \cite[11]{Walsh2015-WALRCA-5}) do not.

\end{document}



And here is a toy sources.bib file for the mwe:
@article{Walsh2015-WALRCA-5,
    author = {Sean Walsh and Sean Ebels{-}Duggan},
    date-added = {2024-06-11 02:03:18 -0400},
    date-modified = {2024-06-11 02:03:18 -0400},
    doi = {10.1017/s1755020315000052},
    journal = {Review of Symbolic Logic},
    number = {3},
    pages = {572--606},
    title = {Relative Categoricity and Abstraction Principles},
    volume = {8},
    year = {2015},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://doi.org/10.1017/s1755020315000052},
}

As things stand, when I cite something within parentheses, I get the following inelegant kind of result: (See Frege (1997: 136).)

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Welcome! You can use biblatex-examples.bib for an example. \textcite[See][]{<key>}?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the suggestion, I added a mwe.

@cfr: cool, I didn't know about biblatex-examples.bib. I don't think the [See] optional argument is what I'm looking for—that adds a "See" within the parentheses, before the year, but it does not remove the parentheses, so far as I can tell.

@ptal The idea is to let Biblatex make the outer parentheses so e.g. \textcite[See][for details]{<key>}. If that doesn't get the punctuation right, there are specific commands for the construction of parenthetical text provided by the package. This is much easier than trying to have Biblatex figure out if you've added parentheses manually, even if that is possible at all. Also, if you add them manually, you don't benefit from the parentheses tracking Biblatex provides.

@cfr Oh I see—I'll try that and see if I like the workflow. The parenthetical material is sometimes long, which I imagine would get difficult to handle in this way.

Generally speaking, biblatex cannot track brackets that were added directly (with ( and )) "outside" of text it typesets itself.
In your use cases it appears to me that automatic bracket tracking is not the normal way to go. Instead you should use the correct commands \textcite for textual/narrative citations and \parencite for parenthetical citations. Both of those citation types can be combined with pre- and postnotes.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=false, eprint=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{%
  \iffieldpages{postnote}
    {\addcolon}
    {\addspace}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{sigfridsson} show that Hume's Principle is internally categorical.

But then others do not \parencite[see for example][for details]{worman}.

Blorb \parencite[380]{sigfridsson}

\end{document}



Wonderful, thank you. I didn't know about \parencite.
